Type subscribe function to ensure the callback only takes the right event from a union type
I have a TypeScript function subscribe that is used to subscribe to specific event types extracted from a union type. The function definition and type declarations are as follows:
type Notification = {
    readonly type: "new_photo";
} | {
    readonly type: "liked_photo";
    readonly id: string
} | {
    readonly type: "disliked_photo";
    readonly id: string
}

type EventType = "new_photo" | "liked_photo" | "disliked_photo"


type Subscribers = {
  [K in EventType]?: Set<
    (message: Extract<Notification, { type: K }>) => void
  >;
};

const subscribers: Subscribers = {};

export function subscribe<T extends EventType>(
  type: T,
  callback: (message: Extract<Notification, { type: T }>) => void,
) {
  if (!subscribers[type]) {
    subscribers[type] = new Set(); // error comes here
  }
  subscribers[type]?.add(callback);
  return () => {
    subscribers[type]?.delete(callback);
  };
}

I am encountering the following error in the subscribe function:
Type 'Set<(message: Extract<{ readonly type: "new_photo"; }, { type: T; }> | Extract<{ readonly type: "liked_photo"; readonly id: string & Brand<"PhotoId">; }, { type: T; }> | ... 5 more ... | Extract<...>) => void>' is not assignable to type 'Subscribers[T]'.
  Type 'Set<(message: Extract<{ readonly type: "new_photo"; }, { type: T; }> | Extract<{ readonly type: "liked_photo"; readonly id: string & Brand<"PhotoId">; }, { type: T; }> | ... 5 more ... | Extract<...>) => void>' is not assignable to type 'Set<(message: { readonly type: "new_photo"; }) => void> & Set<(message: { readonly type: "liked_photo"; readonly id: string & Brand<"PhotoId">; }) => void> & Set<...> & ... 8 more ... & Set<...>'.
    Type 'Set<(message: Extract<{ readonly type: "new_photo"; }, { type: T; }> | Extract<{ readonly type: "liked_photo"; readonly id: string & Brand<"PhotoId">; }, { type: T; }> | ... 5 more ... | Extract<...>) => void>' is not assignable to type 'Set<(message: { readonly type: "new_photo"; }) => void>'.
      Type '(message: Extract<{ readonly type: "new_photo"; }, { type: T; }> | Extract<{ readonly type: "liked_photo"; readonly id: string & Brand<"PhotoId">; }, { type: T; }> | ... 5 more ... | Extract<...>) => void' is not assignable to type '(message: { readonly type: "new_photo"; }) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'message' and 'message' are incompatible.
          Type '{ readonly type: "new_photo"; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ readonly type: "new_photo"; }, { type: T; }> | Extract<{ readonly type: "liked_photo"; readonly id: string & Brand<"PhotoId">; }, { type: T; }> | ... 5 more ... | Extract<...>'.ts(2322)

I tried adjusting the type definitions and casting the set, but nothing is properly narrowing down the callback to be of the right type.
Something very similar happens when I try to call the callback like this:
            if (subscribers[m.payload.type]) {
              subscribers[m.payload.type]?.forEach((cb) => cb(m.payload));

Where the payload is properly typed to the right event
Here is a playground link
EDIT:
It is possible to make the erro go away by providing an empty array when initializing the set, but this only makes the error move to a different place, in this case when calling the callback.
Here is an example of a simple caller function:
// Everything remains the same

export function subscribe<T extends EventType>(
  type: T,
  callback: (message: Extract<Notification, { type: T }>) => void,
) {
  if (!subscribers[type]) {
    subscribers[type] = new Set([]); // No error here
  }
  subscribers[type]?.add(callback);
  return () => {
    subscribers[type]?.delete(callback);
  };
}

function callSubscribers(event: Notification) {
  if (subscribers[event.type]) {
    subscribers[event.type]?.forEach((cb) => {
      cb(event); // Here the error is that you can not provide the event, instead it expects never
    });
  }
}

Here is an updated playground link

TS can't follow correlations in union types like callSubscribers() requires, see ms/TS#30581. Assuming you don't want to just use a type assertion, you can use the refactoring approach from ms/TS#47109 as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining or link to a suitable duplicate; if not, what am I missing?

That is a very well documented issue. The problem with the fix in your playground (I think) is that I can’t manually define the notification type as you did. It is coming from my validation library by merging several schemas. Will take a more detailed look at your solution tough

You can always compute my types from your Notification, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question now? If so I'll write up an answer, if not, what remains unaddressed?

I think you're right and this is the right answer. You can write an answer and I will accept it

The problem with callSubscribers() is that you're trying to correlate multiple utterances of the event variable, which is of a union type. It would be fine if TypeScript could look at event, narrow it provisionally to each member of the union, and check subscribers[event.type]?.forEach(cb => cb(event)) for correctness. But it can't, instead it sees the first event and the second event as essentially independent union typed values.  And it therefore worries that event might not be the proper argument for cb.
The lack of direct support for correlated union types is described in microsoft/TypeScript#30581. The recommended approach, if you care about getting TypeScript to follow your logic, is to refactor to use generics in the manner described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.  The idea is to write things in terms of a "base" key-value mapping type, and in terms of generic indexes into that type, or into mapped types over that type.
For your example, the "base type" looks like
type Subscribable = {
    new_photo: {};
    liked_photo: {
        readonly id: string;
    };
    disliked_photo: {
        readonly id: string;
    };
}

Note that you can compute this from Notification using key remapping in mapped types:
type Subscribable = { [T in Notification as T['type']]:
  { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, "type">]: T[K] }
}

Then you can rewrite the Notification type as a distributive object type that explicitly keeps track of the general relationship between the key and the value in terms of Subscribable:
type MyNotification<K extends keyof Subscribable = keyof Subscribable> =
  { [P in K]: { type: P } & Subscribable[P] }[K]

And Subscribers and subscribe() are also rewritten in terms of Subscribable:
type Subscribers = { [K in keyof Subscribable]?:
  Set<(message: Subscribable[K]) => void>
}

const subscribers: Subscribers = {};

function subscribe<K extends keyof Subscribable>(
  type: K,
  callback: (message: Subscribable[K]) => void,
) {
  if (!subscribers[type]) {
    subscribers[type] = new Set([]);
  }
  subscribers[type]?.add(callback);
  return () => {
    subscribers[type]?.delete(callback);
  };
}

Finally, callSubscribers() has to be made generic:
function callSubscribers<K extends keyof Subscribable>(event: MyNotification<K>) {
  if (subscribers[event.type]) {
    subscribers[event.type]?.forEach((cb) => {
      cb(event);
    });
  }
}

This works because the compiler can see that event.type is of generic type K, that subscribers[event.type] is of generic type Set<(message: Subscribable[K]) => void>, and thus that each entry is of generic type (message: Subscribable[K]) => void, and since event is of type MyNotification<K>, which is assignable to Subscribable[K], it is accepted as an argument.
It's fairly convoluted and only something I'd recommend if you really want the compiler to care about following the logic. Otherwise you might just use type assertions to silence the warnings.
Playground link to code
